# How to use i18n in electron main process with Quasar 2

Tags: electron, internationalization, vuejs3, vite, quasar

How do I use i18n in main process (menu and try) in project created with quasar cli with vite.

I'm currently using i18next and i18next-fs-backend for of the menus and tray. It's configured to use the same locale files in src/i18n that the render process uses. This works in dev mode, but prod build displays the keys, not the translations.

I have i18next config set to `loadPath: "./src/i18n/{{lng}}.json"`

Answer (score 1):

You may use i18next-electron-fs-backend instead: https://github.com/reZach/i18next-electron-fs-backend

Answer (score 1):

I'm the maintainer of [`i18next-electron-fs-backend`](https://github.com/reZach/i18next-electron-fs-backend). Try these steps (a working implementation of this package is found within the [`secure-electron-template`](https://github.com/reZach/simple-electron-template/) repository).

**import the backend**

```js
import i18n from "i18next";
import {
  initReactI18next
} from "react-i18next";
import backend from "i18next-electron-fs-backend";

i18n
  .use(backend)
  .use(initReactI18next)
  .init({
    backend: {
      loadPath: "./app/localization/locales/{{lng}}/{{ns}}.json",
      addPath: "./app/localization/locales/{{lng}}/{{ns}}.missing.json",
      ipcRenderer: window.api.i18nextElectronBackend // important!
    },

    // other options you might configure
    debug: true,
    saveMissing: true,
    saveMissingTo: "current",
    lng: "en"
  });

export default i18n;
```

**update your preload script**

```js
const {
    contextBridge,
    ipcRenderer
} = require("electron");
const backend = require("i18next-electron-fs-backend");

contextBridge.exposeInMainWorld(
    "api", {
        i18nextElectronBackend: backend.preloadBindings(ipcRenderer, process)
    }
);
```

**update your main process**

```js
const {
  app,
  BrowserWindow,
  session,
  ipcMain
} = require("electron");
const backend = require("i18next-electron-fs-backend");
const fs = require("fs");

let win;

async function createWindow() {  
  win = new BrowserWindow({
    width: 800,
    height: 600,
    webPreferences: {
      contextIsolation: true,
      preload: path.join(__dirname, "preload.js")
    }
  });

  backend.mainBindings(ipcMain, win, fs); // <- configures the backend
  
  // ...
}

app.on("ready", createWindow);

app.on("window-all-closed", () => {
  // On macOS it is common for applications and their menu bar
  // to stay active until the user quits explicitly with Cmd + Q
  if (process.platform !== "darwin") {
    app.quit();
  } else {
    i18nextBackend.clearMainBindings(ipcMain);
  }
});
```

What I found in [an issue](https://github.com/reZach/secure-electron-template/issues/36) reported awhile ago, was that on production the resources weren't being loaded properly, maybe the i18n.mainconfig.js file I have can help lead you in a particular fix..?

**i18n.mainconfig.js**

```js
const i18n = require("i18next");
const backend = require("i18next-fs-backend");
const whitelist = require("./whitelist");

// On Mac, the folder for resources isn't
// in the same directory as Linux/Windows;
// https://www.electron.build/configuration/contents#extrafiles
const path = require("path");
const isMac = process.platform === "darwin";
const isDev = process.env.NODE_ENV === "development";
const prependPath = isMac && !isDev ? path.join(process.resourcesPath, "..") : ".";

i18n
  .use(backend)
  .init({
    backend: {
      loadPath: prependPath + "/app/localization/locales/{{lng}}/{{ns}}.json",
      addPath: prependPath + "/app/localization/locales/{{lng}}/{{ns}}.missing.json"
    },
    debug: false,
    namespace: "translation",
    saveMissing: true,
    saveMissingTo: "current",
    lng: "en",
    fallbackLng: false, // set to false when generating translation files locally
    supportedLngs: whitelist.langs
  });

module.exports = i18n;
```